# How to add attribute to form input HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you add an attribute to an HTML element?  I tried the following but the attribute is not updating.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#username_input').attr('value', 'something')
  console.log(getUrlVars()["username"]);
  console.log($('#username_input'));
  console.log($('#username_input').css("display"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Album title"></input>
  <input id="username_input" type="text" name="username" style="display:none;" />
  <button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-success">+ Add Album</button>
</form>
```

Comment: you can use `val()` to update value

Comment: What makes you think the value isn't updating? I ran your code and inspected the element in the DOM, and saw `value="something"`.

Comment: invalid html `</input>`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n4pd9ty1/ it is working the input that is hidden has the value something just like in the code. i just got rid of the line `console.log(getUrlVars()["username"]);` because it is not defined

Comment: I didnt add in the lines above and below my code.. I also changed the /> to </input> at the end and it still wont work...

Comment: did you check the hidden input it has the value. check it it is like this `<input id="username_input" type="text" name="username" style="display:none;" value="something">` <------- it is having the value something just like what you wanted

Comment: Yes I checked. I was having the javascript in the <head> but I moved it to the end of the <body> and it still wont work... Any suggestions?

Comment: put your code after the script that should suffice

Comment: But I put my javascript code in the <head> and it wont work.....

Comment: If it's in `$(document).ready()` it doesn't matter where you put it.

Comment: Do you have any idea whats wrong then?

Comment: In fact no attribute is being added to any element

Comment: When I go into the Elements tab of the console, I see `<input id="username_input" type="text" name="username" style="display:none;" value="something">`.

Comment: OHHHH the elements tab is updated and not the source?

Comment: Change `console.log($('#username_input'));` to `console.log($('#username_input').attr('value'));` and you should see it.

Comment: I can see it in elements too... but how come the source is not updated?

Comment: Nothing you do to the DOM affects the original source.

Comment: But when I did console.log() it wouldnt show up either

Comment: You're not logging the attribute.

Comment: Oh thanks guys I think it worked! But could you please answer and explain what all I was doing wrong so that I can give you guys an approved answer thing?

Answer (score 0):

You're not logging the attribute value, you're logging the jQuery object containing the element. Change

```
console.log($("#username_input"));
```

to

```
console.log($("#username_input").attr("value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax problem. just add ";" to end of the second line

**$('#username_input').attr('value', 'something');**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#username_input').attr('value', 'something');
  console.log(getUrlVars()["username"]);
  console.log($('#username_input'));
  console.log($('#username_input').css("display"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Album title"></input>
  <input id="username_input" type="text" name="username" style="display:none;" />
  <button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-success">+ Add Album</button>
</form>
```